# How to freeze tablix column headings when exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to freeze a tablix's column headings when exporting to Excel, without having a Header element?

Might I add that the tablix is not the first element on the report, but below a logo and textbox.